# Concatenate rows based on Group By in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, concatenation

I have a table that consists of notes people have made against a job number. This data was taken off an old system which stored each line of text as a new table row. What I want to do is to join each line together to form a single string for each job number.

So the following table

```
JobNo | Line | Notes  
C1234 |  1   | blah blah blah.......  
C1234 |  2   | blah blah blah.....  
C1234 |  3   | blah blah blah.  
C1235 |  1   | blah blah blah blah blah blah.  
C1236 |  1   | blah blah blah....
```

Would become

```
JobNo | Notes  
C1234 | blah blah blah....... blah blah blah..... blah blah blah.  
C1235 | blah blah blah blah blah blah.  
C1236 | blah blah blah....
```

Comment: What database are you using?  What have you tried so far?  (Edit your question with any attempted SQL.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's TSQL try using [`STUFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) with a [`FOR XML PATH`](http://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/) :-

(Note this will only work with sql server 2005 onwards)

```
SELECT
   JobNo,
   STUFF(
     (SELECT ' ' + Notes
      FROM MyTable
      WHERE JobNo = a.JobNo
      FOR XML PATH (''))
      , 1, 1, '')  AS URLList
FROM MyTable AS a
GROUP BY JobNo
```

See this **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6d6ec/4)** working example